# Reduce two finger scroll distance on touchpad

Tags: fedora, touchpad, libinput

I recently installed Fedora on my Dell XPS laptop (9360) but the touchpad has been giving me issues. Overall, it doesn't seem very responsive (compared to Windows on the same machine and other laptops). The main issue is two finger scroll distance. If I start at the center of the touchpad, scrolling isn't detected until my fingers are about 1/4" from the top of the touchpad (leaving little room to actually scroll)

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DELL08AF:00 06CB:76AF Touchpad            id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

I was having some issues with the touchpad disconnecting/stop working so I also disabled the PS/2 device per some forums

```
$ cat /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/41-synaptics-quirks.conf 
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
    MatchProduct "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchOS "Linux"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Option "Ignore" "on"
EndSection
```

Comment: What driver version are you using?  And what is the model name/number of the touchpad?

Comment: Where can I get those from?

Comment: Name         : xorg-x11-drv-libinput
Version      : 0.29.0
Release      : 1.fc31
Architecture : x86_64

Comment: input: DELL08AF:00 06CB:76AF Touchpad